# How do I counter headwinds in the flying minigame?

Tags: okamiden

After Chibiteratsu recovers Kurow's wings, you fly towards a city in the clouds with a minigame that involves countering gusts of wind. I can counter left and right winds by drawing loops in the opposite direction, but how do I counter headwinds that blow me backwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a spiral pattern to blow wind forwards.

The game doesn’t mention this directly. The information is hidden in the drawing tips for Galestorm.

[image: Galestorm spiral pattern]